# Disabling the URL encoding in Guzzle

Tags: php, url, guzzle

I have been trying to download a file in Guzzle and it acts wired, Then I noticed that the request URL has gone haywire. I don't understand how to use the `setEncodingType(false);` function.

This is what I have right now.

```
public class Foo{



    private $client;
    private $loginUrl = 'https://<site>/login';
    private $parseUrl = 'https://<site>/download';

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/guzzle/autoloader.php';

        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true, 'allow_redirects' => [
            'max' => 10,        // allow at most 10 redirects.
            'strict' => true,      // use "strict" RFC compliant redirects.
            'referer' => true,      // add a Referer header
            'protocols' => ['https'], // only allow https URLs
            'track_redirects' => true
        ]]);


    }



    public function download(){
       $q_params = array('param_a'=> 'a', 'param_b'=>'b');
       $target_file = APPPATH.'files/tmp.log';
       $response = $this->client->request('GET', $this->parseUrl,['query'=>$reportVars, 'sink' => $target_file]);

    }


}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I use disable the url encoding in  the above code?

Comment: What version of Guzzle?

Comment: @ShaunBramley I am using the latest vesion

Comment: How are you determining it's going haywire? You've obfuscated the parameters and the parameter values, so it's hard to see how urlencoding would've caused issues here. Additionally, `$reportVars` is not in your `download()` function's scope, which is likely causing some trouble. Same thing for `$q_params` never being used in the Guzzle call.

Answer (score 0):

Cursory glance through the code of [GuzzleHttp\Client::applyOptions](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php) indicates that when you utilze the "query" request option the query will be built to PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 as shown below:

```
    if (isset($options['query'])) {
        $value = $options['query'];
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = http_build_query($value, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
        }
        if (!is_string($value)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('query must be a string or array');
        }
        $modify['query'] = $value;
        unset($options['query']);
    }
```

Guzzle utilizes [GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/Uri.php) internally.  Note how the `withoutQueryValue()` and `withQueryValue()` methods will also encode the query string.

I have had a lot of success "hard coding" my query parameters, like the following:

```
$uri = 'http://somewebsite.com/page.html?param_a=1&param2=245';
```

I would like to also note that there is no setEncodingType() within `GuzzleHttp\Client`.

Comment: Is this really how it has to be done? That seems very limiting or awkward.